# How to read a txt file and parse data for display in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I pretty new to python and need some help. I need to read all the values from a txt file and display it to the GUI.
The txt file i choose as a file operation needed as requirement therefore i choose a text file store the dictionary. 
I'm using python 3 and would appreciate the help.

```
from tkinter import *
#read the file
file = open("./ppl.txt", "r")
courses = file.readlines()
print(courses)

root = Tk()

for course in courses:
    temp_text = courses
    Label(root, text=temp_text).pack()

mainloop()
```

The txt file (`ppl.txt`) is:

```
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '27', 'Sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Female'}}
```

Now the GUI is showing a messy format:

[image: scrrenshot of messy output being displayed]

I would like it to be in GUI example:

```
Name: John, Age:27, Sex: Male
Name: Marie, Age:22, Sex: Female
```

Comment: A small comment; read from your file using [`with open("./ppl.txt", "r") as file:`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) so that it's appropriately closed when you're done.

Comment: @martineau yes it is a python dictionary

Comment: @raindris11: Is it mandatory to you to name it `ppl.txt` instead of `ppl.py`

Comment: @stovfl yes it is mandatory to call from other files such as txt file which consists of the dictionary.

Comment: I accept this **requirement**, but it's unusual. I recommend to [edit] your question and explain in detail, **why** do you have to do so.

Comment: If the file was instead named `ppl.py` you could `import` it to get the dictionary it defines — which would make formatting it a lot easier.

Comment: @martineau thanks for your reply. The requirement is to be in txt file that consist of dictionary. Is there other ways other than change the file?

Comment: You could copy the file into another temporary file with `.py` at the end, but I think there's a workaround that would be simpler to implement (and faster) — see answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it that involves using the built-in [`runpy.run_path()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path) function to execute the text file as though it was a Python module and return the module globals dictionary, **which is a potential security hazard with untrusted input**.

After executing the code in the text file, it gets the dictionary object that's defined and formats its contents into a list of lines which are subsequently used to make the `Label` widgets.

```
import runpy
from tkinter import *

filepath = "./ppl.txt"

# Execute file as python module and get the module globals dictionary defined.
mod_dict = runpy.run_path(filepath, {'__builtins__': None})
people = mod_dict['people']  # Retrieve dictionary defined.

# Format dictionary data into separate lines.
lines = []
for person in people.values():
    line = ', '.join('{}: {}'.format(key, value) for (key, value) in person.items())
    lines.append(line)

root = Tk()

for line in lines:
    Label(root, text=line).pack(anchor=W)

mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of data displayed in tkinter window]